# Using Clonezilla (or alternate) to make a *partial* full disk image of a multi-partition, multi-boot hdd

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, mbr, disk-image, clonezilla

So I have a windows multi-boot system with XP installed first, then windows 7.  I also have further partitions for user data, etc.  I do not fully understand where (and what) data is stored on a pc hard drive, other then the partitions I create (i.e. MBR, partition table, recovery partitions, etc..), but presumably my HDD would look something like this:

```
# HARD DRIVE #
--------------
**{mbr}**
**{secret stuff??}**
**c - XP**
**d - Win7**
e - {user data1}
f - {user data2}
...
```

**What I want to do is get a disk image that contains the MBR, and both OS partitions and anything else 'secret', starting from the beginning of the disk and ending with the end of the windows 7 partition.  I don't have to use clonezilla, but a free tool is desired.**

Why?
Because I want to be able to re-image my hard drive OSes/MBR/'secret stuff' when the hard drive has been in use for a while and has user data in the other partitions, without losing or having to restore (from backup) the current state of the data partitions.

What I read, is that making *partition* images of the OSes only won't get the MBR or other secret data (Win 7 recovery partition for example).
But I don't want kill my user data partitions' data, by restoring a full disk image (since the full disk image would be a snapshoot of my PC fairly soon after I installed my multi-boot OSes, and thus would have invalid user data).

And there are reasons why I still want XP (its network access will be disabled) as a separate OS, but presumably the same question could be asked if I was multi-booting a different combination of OSes.

So does anyone have any suggestions how I can do this (tool and special settings/switches needed) or alternative method that will do the same thing (i.e. restore the 1st "half" of the drive without killing the rest of the drive's data)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Btw, afaik this question has not been asked before.  It is different then asking how to clone a larger, not fully partitioned, drive to a smaller drive.
.
What I am asking how to get a viable partial disk image of a fully partitioned drive, such that some but not all of the (sequential) partitions can be restored with one file image file, including the MBR and any secret partitions (i.e. W7)